# android: install application Programmatically using package installer

Tags: java, android, installation, action, package-managers

I am installing an android application progammatically. A dialog box "Complete Action Using" appears. Many options are available between them "Package Installer". How to choose the "Package Installer" implicitly without asking the user to choose it?

**EDIT**
The code I am using is:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
intent .setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("/mnt/sdcard/download/App.apk")),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Please show the code you are using to attempt to install the application. Also, please show a screenshot of your chooser, to show the "many options" that are available to you.

Comment: I will edit my question.

Comment: Please add `ACTION_VIEW` to your `Intent`.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using this code for that task. I guess you've missed to add the type?

```
Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(myFile);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 3):

Android O and up supports installing application programmatically. For that you need to declare and request `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` permission.

**In your manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

In your activity request permission runtime - direct user to allow permission

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES, Uri.parse("package:".concat("your.package.name"))));
```

After this you need to implement download manager and file provider and install app after it is downloaded

follow [this article](https://androidwave.com/download-and-install-apk-programmatically/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to redirect to Android's package installer without choose installer dialog, use below code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
```

if you want to open "Choose installer dialog(If any other package installer app exist in your device)", use below code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
```

***Notice the parameter in Intent***

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not available to 3rd party applications. That would be an security risk for android. However, an 3rd party application can ask built-in installer if you want to install an package. Here are the codes for installing apk programmatically.

**App from Google Play**

```
Intent installIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
installintent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.package.megaapp"));
startActivity(installIntent);
```

**APK file (without installer prompt)**

```
Intent installIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
installIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/yourapk.apk"));
startActivity(installIntent);
```

But you cannot install apks like Google Play does it, not unless your app is system and your device is rooted.

Comment: It is entirely possible. Use this. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInstaller